# WSO2AM 2.0.0 scope definition - bug or mistake?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Trying you the new WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 For the basic setup so far looks ok, but when I'm trying to authorize specific resources for scopes (assign a scope to a resource as described [in the article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/12/article-role-based-access-control-for-apis-exposed-via-wso2-api-manager-using-oauth-2.0-scopes/)), the browser console claims:

```
jquery.validate.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined
```

and the scope cannot be selected. Do I do someting wrong or it's a bug? Can the scope be defined and assigned using the swagger file?

Thank you in advance

g.

Comment: Did you add the scope properly using "Add Scopes" button before attaching to a resource..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially answering the questions:

**1. Can the scope be defined and assigned using the swagger file?**

Yes. You need first define them globally under "x-wso2-security" and assign them to resources using "x-scope" elements.

See the example below.

```
swagger: '2.0'
paths:
  /*:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
      x-auth-type: Application & Application User
      x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
      x-scope: api1_read
    post:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
      parameters:
        - name: Payload
          description: Request Body
          required: false
          in: body
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              payload:
                type: string
      x-auth-type: Application & Application User
      x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
info:
  title: api1
  version: '1.2'
x-wso2-security:
  apim:
    x-wso2-scopes:
      - name: read api name
        description: ''
        key: api1_read
        roles: admin
```

Comment: Yes, when the roles are assigned using the swagger file, it works (though - cannot use the same scope names through multiple apis). Apparently the UI is not yet polished. Thank you.